# Regex to select a certain word followed by a integer or decimal?

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to detect the phrase `Figure 1.5:` in a given string. Also, I intend on using this expression in a PHP `preg_replace()` function.

Here are some more examples:

- ...are given. `Figure 2.1:` shows that...
- ...are given. `Figure 3:` shows that...
- ...are given. `Figure 1.16:` shows that...
- ...are given. `Figure 0.4` shows that...
- ...are given. `figure 5.1:` shows that...

With my limited Regex knowledge, I was able to create this:

`/\wFigure \d*\.?\d*/g`

But that doesn't even begin to handle all of the permutations that could occur.

I would appreciate any suggestions that you might have.

Comment: Why do you use `\w` before `Figure`? There is no word char before. Remove it. `'/Figure \d+(?:\.\d+)*/'` or `'/\bFigure\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)*/'` should work.

Comment: The “integer or decimal” part can probably be handled broadly by just something like `([0-9\.]+)` - that would catch “invalid” combinations such as `.9` or `5....6` as well - but how likely would those be to occur in your input data after `Figure ` anyway?

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew Your first suggestion worked prefectly. Thank you ever so much. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points here:

- You are using `\w` at the start, perhaps, as a word boundary. In fact, `\w` matches a letter, digit or `_` and actually requires this char to be at the exact location. However, there is no word char before `Figure`, so you need to either remove `\w` or replace with `\b`.
- `preg_replace` replaces all non-overlapping occurrences by default, you do not need the `g` modifier
- `\d*\.?\d*` is fine here, but since you want to match any digits followed with zero or more occurrences of `.` and digits you can use a more specific pattern like `\d+(?:\.\d+)*`.

You can use

```php
preg_replace('/Figure \d+(?:\.\d+)*/', '', $string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO2iQV/1).

*Details*:

- `Figure` - a string
- - a space (replace with `\s+` to match any one or more whitespaces, and consider adding `u` flag after last `/` if you need to find all Unicode whitespaces)
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - zero or more occurrences of `.` and one or more digits.